# Ruby keeping a count from a list

Tags: ruby

I am grabbing some data from a list and I want to rank the items. There are 100 items from the list. When I run my code I get the data I am looking for but before every data I get "100" when it should be "1. ... 2. ..." Here is my code

```
lineList = mdoc.read.split("\n")
songList = []

count = 0

lineList.each do |line|
  matchObj = line.match(/<td>(\S+.+)<\/td>/)
  if matchObj then
    songList.push(matchObj.captures[0])
    count = count + 1
  end
end

songList.each do |title|
  puts count.to_s + ". " + title  
end
```

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is how bad things happen. Can you use a proper parser like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org)? Also the `then` is typically omitted in most Ruby code, it's extraneous. Likewise, variable and method names should be like `line_list`, all lower-case with underscores. Capital letters have significant meaning in Ruby.

Comment: Your loop to `puts count` does not begin until the `lineList.each do` loop is completed, so `count` = `100` by the time you start `puts`ing it. You can either output the count from within the `lineList.each` loop or do something like tadman suggests (in which case you do not need to define `count` at all in this example).

Comment: @Joseph I did what you said by putting "count" before the loop ends and when I ran it, the result is that it gives me the data but now instead of "100" I get "1758" which is the total number of lines in the HTML document from which I am grabbing my data from.

Comment: hmm, hard to say what's going on without reviewing the revised code, but I would expect that if you `puts count.to_s + ". " + matchObj.captures[0]` after the `end` from the `if matchObj` statement but before the `end` of the `lineList.each do` statement you would get the results you want.

Comment: @Joseph thank you that worked!

Answer (score 3):

The typical way to display a list is this:

```
song_list.each_with_index do |song, i|
  puts '%d. %s' % [ i + 1, song ]
end
```

This uses the string formatting function [`%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-25) and [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index).